# Ruby- CSV merge field value

Tags: ruby, csv

I started learning Ruby this weekend. I'm working on a script that is going to read a CSV file that has a Date field and a Time field, and merge the values into a new `DateTime` field written to the output.

What I have is partially working, but the problem I have is the Date and Time values are comma separated. I would like to remove the comma and replace it with a space. How can I remove the comma and merge the values together?

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb", :headers => true) do |output|
  CSV.foreach("input.csv", :headers => true, :return_headers => true) do |row|
    if row.header_row?
      output << (row << 'DateTime')
    else
      output << (row << row['Date'].to_s << (row['Time'].to_s))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show us the CSV headers and the first line of the records in CSV.

Comment: I don't the file should be opened in 'wb' mode.  'b' means binary, and you are creating a text file, not a binary file.  This might not make a difference on Unix, but it's not portable and is bad practice in general, since it says to the reader 'this will be a binary file'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` to replace contents in a string.

```
date = row['Date']
time = row['Time']

datetime = "#{date} #{time}".tr(',', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb", :headers => true) do |output|
  output << 'DateTime'

  CSV.foreach("input.csv", :headers => true, :return_headers => true, :header_converters => :symbolize) do |row|
    output << ["#{row[:date] row[:time]}"]
  end
end
```

The changes here represent this functionality:

- `:return_headers => true` converts header field names to symbol, which can significantly improve performance for even moderate-length CSV files
- Moved the header output outside the input CSV loop, as the headers can safely be written before any row data
- Use the efficient column reference mechanism for `row[:date]` and `row[:time]`
- wrote the row data as an array (of one element), consisting of the interpolated string containing both `row[:date]` and `row[:time]`